# Linearity of a differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomials in $x$ and $y$ of degree $\leq 2$. Show that the differential operator $T=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is a linear operator on $V$.

Do we pick any polynomial in $x$ and $y$ and show the 2 axioms of linearity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sum of two linear operator is again linear operator. I think you already learned $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$ are linear operators. (otherwise it's extremely easy to show. Just follow the definition)

Answer (score 1):

You can start the proof like this: "let $p(x,y)=\sum_{i+j\leq 2} a_{ij}x^iy^j$ and $q(x,y)=\sum_{i+j\leq 2}b_{ij}x^iy^j$ be two degree $2$ bivariate polynomials in $V$, then...".

However you can't choose two specific polynomials and show that the axioms hold for just those two; you have to show that the axioms hold regardless of the choice of polynomials, hence the above setup.